# undefined reference to `BIO_s_mem'

Tags: c, gcc, openssl

Here's my code:

```c
#include <openssl/bio.h>
int main (void)
{
    BIO* bo = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());
}
```

I'm compiling my code by doing `gcc -lcrypto test.c`.

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the arguments in the wrong order, try `gcc test.c -lcrypto`

See [why order matters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc/409470)